# Grammar books with exercises and answer key for autonomous study of Italian

Tags: resource-request, physical-resources, grammar, italian

I am looking for a grammar book or series of grammar books for Italian that match the following criteria:

- the book or books must be in Italian, i.e. all grammar rules and instructions must be in Italian (not English, Spanish or another language);
- content should be organised in chapters that first explain a set of grammar rules and then provide a number of exercises that apply these rules;
- there must be an answer key (the answer key may be a separate volume);
- the book must be appropriate for self study (the presence of an answer key is not sufficient; some books of this type are intended for teachers of Italian).

I am looking for books for the levels A1 - B2 (starting at B2 is also OK). The first three criteria may be easy to fulfil, but the last criterion is essential and it may not be obvious whether a book matches this criterion just by looking at the book cover in an online bookshop. Answers that are based on personal experience using such books would be especially appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I've been a self learner of Italian for many years (and, in fact, I'm still learning Italian) and this is a grammar book that I found very useful for self study:

> Federica Colombo, *Grammatica e pratica della lingua italiana per studenti stranieri* (edizioni ELI, 2006).

It covers levels from A2 to B1 (in principle, it doesn't cover B2, but I found it also useful to study grammar when I was preparing for a B2 exam). All the explanations are written in Italian and, in my opinion, are easy to understand. It has exercises with an answer key at the end of the book. It has also some tests at the end of the book.